# NOT IN condition in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can anyone tell me the exact syntax for NOT IN condition in SQL on two columns.

This is my query written in VBA.

```
strNewSql = "SELECT distinct(tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber), tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ID FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber = tblEventLog.PartNumber"

strNewSql = strNewSql & " WHERE (tblEventLog.PartNumber) Not In(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper') AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """ AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber;"
```

I want to change this sub query like, it should apply on the combination of two columns as follows:

```
strNewSql = "SELECT tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ID FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber = tblEventLog.PartNumber"

strNewSql = strNewSql & " WHERE (((tblEventLog.PartNumber, tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl) Not In(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber,tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper') AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """ AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber);"
```

But this is not working.....

Comment: What do you need, the combination of the columns together doesn't work or the data is not in either column?

Comment: What do you mean by two columns?

Comment: HLGEM,combination of two columns..

Comment: It would help to know which version of MS-Access you're using as that might affect the answer.

Comment: I can't think of a single version difference for this kind of simple SQL in any version of Access going back to Version 2. The only thing that could make a difference if you're in A2003 or later and have SQL 92 mode turned on, but I don't even think that would make a difference (unless you're using a SQL 92 keyword, none of which jump out at me). In short, I really don't think the version of Access makes the slightest difference -- everything in this query has always been supported.

Comment: Have you considered just JOINing the two tables on the two fields you want to match? I can't see a reason why that wouldn't work. That is, I just don't see any reason to jump to a subquery here. Where are you using the resultset? Is it in a form that needs to be editable? If so, you may have to do the JOIN in the subquery and return your main table's PK field as the SELECT in the IN subquery.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't use `IN` with more than one column but you can usually achieve the same effect using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.col1 = tbl1.col1
        AND tbl2.col2 = tbl1.col2
)
```

Answer (score 5):

General syntax:

```
where col not in (items)
```

Items can be

- a list of items -- `(4,5,3,5,2)` or  `('243','3','cdds')` or any other datatype.
- Or a select statement `(select hatefulthings from table)`

---

*Addition 6 years later*

All major platforms support tuples with NOT IN, for example

```
SELECT *
FROM empoyee
WHERE (empID, @date) NOT IN 
  (SELECT empID, vacationDay
   FROM empVacation
  )
```

In this example we select everything from the employee table where the tuple of employee id and date are not in a table containing vacation days.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Is this what you need?

```
SELECT *
FROM
  MY_TABLE MT
WHERE 'Smith' NOT IN (MT.FIRST_NAME)
  AND 'Smith' NOT IN (MT.LAST_NAME)
```

This will show you all records where the search phrase ("Smith") is in neither the first_name nor the last_name column.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant

```
SELECT *
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) NOT IN (SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
                                          FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE)
```

This is allowed under Oracle - not sure about SQL Server.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Ohh ya, I tried same syntax but it didnot work ..well I am working on access platform and I should write query in the VBA.

Comment: I've retagged the question so that perhaps the MS Access experts can look at this.

Comment: It might work in Access, but it won't use indexes, so it could be very, very slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from some_table
where (((Some_Value) Not IN (Select Column1 & Column2 from Some_Other_Table)));
```

I saw where you indicated this was for Access

Comment: check out my query once..    strNewSql = "SELECT tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ID FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail LEFT JOIN tblEventLog ON tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber = tblEventLog.PartNumber"
   strNewSql = strNewSql & " WHERE (tblEventLog.PartNumber) Not In(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber,tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl FROM tblEventLog WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper') AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """ AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber;"

Comment: It can't possibly work because the subquery returns two columns. Only a single-column SELECT can be used in an IN subquery.

Comment: `Column1 & Column2` counts as one column, but I think this may be a chancy approach if both columns are numeric.

Comment: The concatenated value of two columns is not necessarily going to be the same as a join on the same columns. What if values in Column1 and Column2 can overlap? Say, it's a pair of firstname/lastname fields. Smith could be a firstname or a lastname, and if one field is Null `Smith & Null` would result in the same as `Null & Smith` and would match, but it wouldn't be an appropriate match. That aside, given that this solution can't use the indexes, it seems like a complete non-starter to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking, but I gather that you would like to have a NOT IN condition based on two columns instead of just one.

As an example, lets say you have a column called F_Name and another called L_Name (both variable in size), and that you want to exclude specific combination of those names from another table that has them already combined as NAME.  In that case, you could do this:

```
select F_name
     , L_name
     , col1
     , coln
  from mytable1
 where F_name                  -- First name (variable length)
    || ' '                     -- appended to a blank space
    || L_name                  -- appended to the last name (v)
       not in                  -- is not one of these names
     ( select name
         from mytable2
        where ...
     )
```

The main issue with this query is that you must get the formatting just right so that they can match up exactly.

If you are dealing with a combination of fields with different types, like numeric and timestamps, then use any of the conversion commands (DECIMAL, INTEGER, CHAR, SUBSTR ...) at your disposal to convert to text equal and then match it up accordingly.