# SQL Not Found Condition

Tags: php, sql

I have a php script that tries to find a particular name in a database where the specified program is `$q`, a variable passed from an html page. I'm very new to this so I'm having trouble figuring out how to code an `if not found, then display` type of message. Below is what I currently have:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM names WHERE program='".$q."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<div class='header'>Program Name:</div>";
        echo "<div class='data'>";
        echo $row['program'];
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

And I need it to echo a message saying if nothing was found. I tried looking at [NOT IN condition in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197510/not-in-condition-in-sql) and http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php along with other things on the internet but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use th php function

```
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

to check results found

So your code should be like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM names WHERE program='".addslashes($q)."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<div class='header'>Program Name:</div>";
        echo "<div class='data'>";
        echo $row['program'];
        echo "</div>";
    }
else
    echo "No data found";
```

please note i added

```
addslashes($q)
```

in query, in order to avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I'll try it right now - how does addslashes help with SQL injection problems?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM names WHERE program='".$q."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $found = false;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $found = true;
        echo "<div class='header'>Program Name:</div>";
        echo "<div class='data'>";
        echo $row['program'];
        echo "</div>";
    }
    if ($found == false)
        echo "I found nothing";
```