# In Access, is it possible to select fields from similar tables in front end & back end copies on different drives?

Tags: ms-access-2010, sql

I have a split Access 2010 database. Users have a copy of this database on their laptops and there is a main copy that resides on the I: drive server. Two tables exist for input on all copies: **tblMedData** and **tblMyMedData**. Users can perform a synchronization that moves the tblMyMedData data from their laptops into the tblMedData table on the I: drive server. tblMedData is then copied back to the tblMedData table on the laptop, so they have the latest data residing on their laptop.

The problem we're facing: if a change is made in the tblMedData table on the server, this change gets overwritten during the synchronization. During the synchronization, I've tried using a select query that checks for medications that exist in both the laptop tblMedData table and the server tblMedData table and if there are any differences between these records, but I can't figure out how to do this? Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT tblMedData.* AS tblLaptopMeds, tblMedData.* AS tblServerMeds, tblMedData.Ratio,     
tblMedData.Duration, tblMedData.Withdrawal, tblMedData.WaterOrInject, tblMedData.Deleted
FROM [C:\FolderName\DB.accdb].tblMedData AS tblLaptopMeds INNER JOIN   
[I:\FolderName\Folder\DB_be.accdb].tblMedData AS tblServerMeds ON tblLaptopMeds.InvNo =  
tblServerMeds.InvNo

WHERE (((tblLaptopMeds.Ratio)<>tblServerMeds!Ratio)) Or (((tblLaptopMeds.Duration)    
<>tblServerMeds!Duration)) Or (((tblLaptopMeds.Withdrawal)<>tblServerMeds!Withdrawal))     
Or (((tblLaptopMeds.WaterOrInject)<>tblServerMeds!WaterOrInject)) Or 
(((tblLaptopMeds.Deleted)<>tblServerMeds!Deleted)) Or (((tblLaptopMeds.Ratio)
<>tblServerMeds!Ratio)) Or (((tblLaptopMeds.Duration)<>tblServerMeds!Duration)) Or   
(((tblLaptopMeds.Withdrawal)<>tblServerMeds!Withdrawal)) Or    
(((tblLaptopMeds.WaterOrInject)<>tblServerMeds!WaterOrInject)) Or 
(((tblLaptopMeds.Deleted)<>tblServerMeds!Deleted)) OR
(((tblLaptopMeds.ChangedBy)<>tblServerMeds!ChangedBy));
```

Does anyone have suggestions? Am I making this too complicated?

Comment: "..if a change is made in the tblMedData table on the server, this change gets overwritten during the synchronization." Can you elaborate? Isn't the point of the Linked Table Manager to keep the table data updated so it is accessible by everyone who utilizes the front end?

Comment: The users aren't always in a location where they have access to the I: drive. They often go off-site to use the database. They perform the sync when they're in office.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of searching for missing values:

```
select * from YourTable a
  where a.YourIDField not in
  (select b.YourIDFieldfrom YourTable b
   where a.YourIDField= b.YourIDField)
```

I'm not sure if `Not In` will work in Access (esp if you're examining multiple fields), so try this if it doesn't:

```
 select * from YourTable a
  where a.YourIDField not exists
  (select b.YourIDFieldfrom YourTable b
   where a.YourIDField= b.Your
```

[See this post for similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197510/not-in-condition-in-sql)

I think if you look into what I posted along with [Selecting from 2 databases on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123359/selecting-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-access) you should be able to go figure it out fairly quickly.